# Possible to disable password authentication and only use Google Authenticator for Linux ssh logins?

Tags: ssh, authentication

Is it possible to setup Linux so that Google Authenticator is the only required authentication?

I've had no problem setting up Linux so that password+google auth works, but I've not been able to get *only* google-authenticator to work.

After setting "KbdInteractiveAuthentication yes" in sshd_config, I've added this to /etc/pam.d/sshd:

```
auth sufficient pam_google_authenticator.so
```

(That's the only 'auth' line).

I also tried commenting out:

```
@include common-password
```

However, I'm still prompted for a password.  This is on Debian 12.